# How to get object variable with get_object_vars

Tags: php, json, variables

I'm trying to extract the "error" part from this response:

```
{
    "sp data": {
        "status": {
            "connection_status": "successful",
            "operation_status": "failed",
            "errors": {
                "error": [
                    "email - Field 'email' should be unique"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "operation_status": "failed"
}
```

Been sitting on this for a few hours and every single Googling I tried didn't turn up to be helpful.

Here is the code:

```
        $onecoption_res = json_decode(onecoption_api($onecoption_api_data));
        $onecoption_error = "";


        if(is_object($onecoption_res)){
            if($onecoption_res->operation_status == 'failed') {
                $onecoption_error = get_object_vars($onecoption_res->{'spot data'}->status->errors->{'error[]'});
            }
        }
echo $onecoption_error[0];
```

This returns:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$error[] 
Warning: get_object_vars() expects parameter 1 to be object, null given in
```

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you capturing this reponse?

Comment: Edited the question. The response I've shown here is generated with Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`error` is a property that is array, so get it by `error` not `error[]`:

```
$onecoption_error = $onecoption_res->{'sp data'}->status->errors->error[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work:

```
echo $onecoption_res->{'sp data'}->status->errors->{error}[0]
```

I don't think you need to use get_object_vars, you are just trying to extract the string correct? get_object_vars does something else, check the documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php

Comment: Worked with a little tweak, like @Mohammad suggested: 
`$onecoption_res->{'sp data'}->status->errors->error[0]` - no brackets on `error`.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply access it directly in the echo line after decoding the json if necessary:

```
if (is_string($onecoption_res)) {
    $onecoption_res = json_decode($onecoption_res);
}
echo $onecoption_res->sp_data->status->errors->error[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

What you posted is a JSON string, not an PHP object.

I would recommend however to turn it into an array like this:

```
$onecoption_array = json_decode($onecoption_res, true);
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
$onecoption_error = $onecoption_array['sp data']['status']['errors']['error'];
```